# Office 365/SP Online search bar doesnt not apear on top nav bar

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

The problem is that the 365 search box dosnt not apear on the top nav bar on the sp sites. I'm the tenant admin as it is my dev tenant.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Base on your screenshot, the current page is a classic site page, so you can't see the search bar on top navigation bar, I suggest you create a modern site page and set it to the home page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really, on modern pages it looks the same:
[Screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FJvd.jpg)